# Subset of data with repetitive names

Tags: r

Subset of cricket data with repetitive player names and runs. My question is how many players have scored more than 5000 total runs? Form the subset of those people along with their runs. The data is as follows. A glimpse of the data is below.

```
"Player"    "Runs"---
SM Gavaskar 28
SS Naik 18
AL Wadekar  67
GR Viswanath    4
FM Engineer 32
BP Patel    82
ED Solkar   3
S Abid Ali  17
S Madan Lal 2
S Venkataraghavan   1
BS Bedi 0
SM Gavaskar 20
SS Naik 20
GK Bose 13
AL Wadekar  6
GR Viswanath    32
FM Engineer 4
BP Patel    12
AV Mankad   44
ED Solkar   0
S Abid Ali  6
S Madan Lal 3
SM Gavaskar 36
ED Solkar   8
AD Gaekwad  22
GR Viswanath    37
BP Patel    16
S Abid Ali  
KD Ghavri   
M Amarnath  
FM Engineer 
S Madan Lal 
S Venkataraghavan   
SM Gavaskar 65
FM Engineer 54
```

Please suggest the method. In excel we would have removed the duplicates and applied a `sumif`. How about in R?

Comment: I am assuming you want to total the runs per player, what are the duplicates then?

Comment: Yes sumedh, i need the total runs of each player..The duplicate meaning Gavaskar has  several runs in other matches, so we need to add all the runs of his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the data in a csv file in Excel, where the first column, named 'player' represents the player and the second column, named 'runs' represents the number of runs.

```
dat <- read.csv("cricket.csv", header=TRUE) # read in the data
dat.nodup <- tapply(dat$runs, dat$player, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)) # sum runs for each player with duplicate observations
dat.gt5000 <- dat.nodup[which(dat.nodup > 5000)] # keep only records with > 5000 runs
length(dat.gt5000) # Number of players with > 5000 runs
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, the issue is i need to calculate the total sums of each players first since the players are repetitive. Then we can go ahead with your above command.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the answer, i am getting 11 runs with total exceeding 5000 runs from the data using your command (cross verified with excel too). Thanks you so much .